# raised ConnectionResetError when i use set_password in ajax requests

Tags: django

I want to send ajax request named 'client password change'

here is javascript code

```
function sendmailConfirm() {
    var result = confirm("client(client@google.com) password will changed");
    if (result == false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('canceled.');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            'url': '/change/password',
            'method': 'GET',
            'data': {
                'email':'password-change@pass.com',
            },
            'success':function(event){
                alert('success!');
            }
        })
    }
};
```

and view.py is

```
class ChangePW(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            user = User.objects.get(email='password-change@pass.com')
            password = random_password_generate()
            user.set_password(password)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

i do runserver and i clicked the button

but it raised error

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59753)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/Desktop/issue/tving-ui/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/Desktop/issue/tving-ui/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

i cant understand when i remove `user.set_password(password)` it is working

my django version is '3.0.4' and python version is '3.7.1'

thank you :)

**ADD**

utils.py

```
import random

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
number = '1234567890'
symbol = '!#$%()*+,-./:;<>?@[]^_{|}~&'


def random_password_generate():
    al = ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(3))
    nu = ''.join(random.choice(number) for i in range(3))
    sy = ''.join(random.choice(symbol) for i in range(3))
    pw = list(al + nu + sy)
    random.shuffle(pw)
    return ''.join(pw)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in views.py can u plese check the type of variable password as user.set_password takes raw string as argument . In case if u want random password generator code can be

```
`def gen_uniqueid():
    captial=chr(random.randint(65,90))
    lower=chr(random.randint(97,122))
    l=['@','#','$','&']
    special=random.choice(l)
    digits=random.randint(10000,99999)
    digit=str(digits)
    result= captial + lower + special +digit
    return result`
```